# i'm facing an error trying to install or update any package?

Tags: updates, software-installation, configuration

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and 2 or 3 months ago the system was updating but the internet went down then the system couldn't update correctly, since then I'm facing this error:

```
Package operation failed, The installation or removal of a software package failed.
```

I was trying to install vuze torrent package from the Ubuntu Software-Center, but failed according to the preivous error.

Comment: when i tried sudo apt-get udpate, i got this, W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ trusty/contrib amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/download.virtualbox.org_virtualbox_debian_dists_trusty_contrib_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ trusty/contrib i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/download.virtualbox.org_virtualbox_debian_dists_trusty_contrib_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
@bain

Comment: still not solved, any other ideas ?!

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`